# How do i combine autocomplete with google map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, autocomplete, google-api

I'm new to Google map API Can you please help? so far I managed to get an input to autocomplete. and I got the map running. from here how do I combine the two such that when I choose an Area (input) from the autocomplete list the map goes to the selected area. 
I found a way to initiate a map with an autocomplete. but I want them to be initiated separately and make the input affect the map. Here is my code where do I go from here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <body>
             <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location"/>
             <pre id="placeInfo"></pre>
             <div id="map"></div>
            <script>
                  var map;
                  function initMap1() {
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                      zoom: 8
                    });
                  }

            function initMap2() {
              var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
              var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
              autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                if (!place.geometry) {
                  window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
                  return;
                }

                var address = '';
                if (place.address_components) {
                  address = [
                    (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                    (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                    (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                  ].join(' ');
                }

                document.getElementById('placeInfo').innerHTML = '<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address;    
              });
            }
            </script>
             <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API-key]&libraries=places&callback=initMap2"
             async defer></script>
             <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API-key]&callback=initMap1"
             async defer></script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: `You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one comment, part of why you are having issues is that you are including the map twice. You only need one script tag where you load the map. This is the one you should be using:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API-key]&libraries=places&callback=initMap2"
         async defer></script>
```

Also, you don't have any CSS, so the div containing the map may not display well. I'd recommend adding the following CSS to your code:

```
#map {
 height: 100%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

I also noticed that you had a different callback function for each script tag where you bootsrap the JS API. Since you only need one of those script tags, I'd recommend combining the two callback functions into one.

You mentioned that you want the input from the autocomplete to affect the map. You can do this by altering the map object in your autocomplete actionlistener function:

```
map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
```

I have made a JSBin to demonstrate this for you. I separated the HTML from the JavaScript code and added the CSS I suggested. The JSBin looks like it works well. For security I have removed my API key from the JSBin, please insert your own to use this sample:

http://jsbin.com/xilepukure/1/edit?html,css,js,output

I hope this helps!